# TYPO3 fluid: How to have well-formed "and" conditions?

Tags: typo3, fluid

Single [conditions in TYPO3's fluid](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Syntax.html#boolean-conditions) template engine can be combined with `&&`:

```
<f:if condition="{data.slug}!== '/' && {data.slug}!== '/main'">
    <f:render partial="Page/Linkback" arguments="{menu:linkback}"></f:render>
</f:if>
```

Unfortunately the `&&` make the HTML file non-wellformed in the XML sense, which means I cannot check for missing closing tags with `xmllint`.

What can I do to combine conditions with "and" while keeping the ability to check the files with xmllint for well-formedness?

Comment: Did you add the data for xml schemas ?

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true"
>
   <f:if condition="{data.slug}!== '/' && {data.slug}!== '/main'">
       <f:render partial="Page/Linkback" arguments="{menu:linkback}"></f:render>
   </f:if>
</html>

Comment: xml schemata have nothing to do with well-formedness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, as ampersand is not permitted as XML attribute value: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue

However HTML allows it (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes), so why not make in an HTML document instead?

Comment: How can I validate html files on command line (find e.g. unclosed tags, broken attribute definitions etc)? that's much easier with xml.

Comment: @cweiske try the terms `parser`, `linter` and `beautifier` instead of `validator`, perhaps that does what you really intend. Which tool is the right depends on your actual need, which isn't clear from your comments, as it seems more than syntax, but less than semantics.